# How to get rid of "500 Internal Server Error" using ui5-middleware-simpleproxy

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I built an SAPUI5 app using [UI5 Tooling](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/) and now I'm having trouble connecting it to an OData service.
[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

---

Since the real url to the OData Service is not public, let's just call it:

```
http://app99.sap.domain.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_DOMAIN_SRV/
```

and opening it in my browser, adding `$metadata?sap-language=DE` at the end, works - I get the XML metadata document.

---

These are the files I tried to change to connect to the OData service:

> - webapp
>
>   - manifest.json
> - package.json
> - ui5.yaml

Adding a `"dataSources"`-object and a `"models"`-object in `manifest.json`

```
{
  "sap.app": {
    ...
    "dataSources": {
      "oDataService": {
        "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_DOMAIN_SRV/",
        "type": "OData"
      }
    }
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    ...
    "models": {
      ...
      "": {
        "dataSource": "oDataService",
        "preload": true,
        "settings": {
          "useBatch": false
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I also tried changing the `"uri"` value to the real link, `http://app99.sap.domain.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_DOMAIN_SRV/`, but then I expectedly get a `Cross-Origin` error:
[image: Cross-Origin Error]

So I tried setting up a proxy by adding this to my `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "ui5-middleware-simpleproxy": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "ui5": {
    "dependencies": [
      "ui5-middleware-simpleproxy"
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

and adding this to my `ui5.yaml` file:

```
...
server:
  customMiddleware:
    - name: ui5-middleware-simpleproxy
      mountPath: /sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_DOMAIN_SRV
      afterMiddleware: compression
      configuration:
        baseUri: "http://app99.sap.domain.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_DOMAIN_SRV/"
```

hoping that now
`http://localhost:8080/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_DOMAIN_SRV/$metadata?sap-language=DE`
would turn into
`http://app99.sap.domain.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_DOMAIN_SRV/$metadata?sap-language=DE`
and it would work, but that isn't the case - I just get the error from the screenshot on top.

Any idea what I am missing?
I really want to make it work with this [ui5-middleware-simpleproxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui5-middleware-simpleproxy), because I don't want to start up two servers manually (the UI5 Tooling one and another one for the proxy). Currently I just need to do `ui5 serve` and everything works out of the box.

Comment: Note to self: maybe it's related to this https://github.com/petermuessig/ui5-ecosystem-showcase/issues/313 ? - I'll try with `--h2` and see if anything gets better...

Comment: nah, `--h2` didn't solve it for me

Comment: I think it has to do with the paths. I'm not sure your mountPath, oData URI and baseURI should all have the full service in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing the config in `ui5.yaml` it worked.
I don't quite understand how the relationship between `mountPath` and `baseUri` works and why it worked this way, but some problems can be solved with try and error like in my case :D

```
...
server:
  customMiddleware:
    - name: ui5-middleware-simpleproxy
      mountPath: /sap/opu/odata/sap
      afterMiddleware: compression
      configuration:
        baseUri: "http://app99.sap.domain.com/sap/opu/odata/sap"
```